# How to call a Java API in ColdFusion?

Tags: api, coldfusion, cfhttp

I am using CF10. I want to know how to call the API of other application.
I would be receiving the Base64 encoded string named "token" from a different Java application. The unencoded version will be the user’s CID, USERNAME, and a UUID separated by comma, something like this: **178,username,a5f5ff2f-8d87-4656-821d-99e62daf512b**. And Base64 encoded string would look like:
MTc4LGFpbXN3ZWIsYTVmNWZmMmYtOGQ4Ny00NjU2LTgyMWQtOTllNjJkYWY1MTJi.

SO, what I have done - I have converted the encoded string into variables. I am catching the string in FORM scope.

```
    <cfif isDefined("Form.token") and len(trim(Form.token)) is not 0>
        <cfset variables.actualTokenString = ToString(ToBinary(Form.token))>

    <cfset Session.CustomerID = ListGetAt(variables.actualTokenString, 1, ",")>


    <cfset Session.UserName = ListGetAt(variables.actualTokenString, 2, ",")>


     <cfset Session.UUID = ListGetAt(variables.actualTokenString, 3, ",")>
</cfif>
```

Now, what I want to do is - Upon receiving the unique login token, I need to call 'that' application's API to validate the token and POST it as a JSON. 
I have used "cfhttp" to do that. Something like below:

```
<cfhttp url="https://AW-tst-staging.pearsondev.com/api/awlegacy" method="POST" result="result">
    <cfhttpparam type="formField" name="CID" value="#Session.CustomerID#">
    <cfhttpparam type="formField" name="USERNAME" value="#Session.UserName#">
    <cfhttpparam type="formField" name="UUID" value="#Session.UUID#">
</cfhttp>
```

Am I doing it right? Can anyone please help?

Comment: Whether or not you are doing it right depends on the requirements of the java API and the results of your efforts.

Comment: @DanBracuk: requirement is pretty clear. I need to call their API (they have already provided the API's) and send them the 'response' in JSON format. The 'response' would be the "same" [Custid, username, uuid] but in JSON format.

Comment: We cannot say you did it correct if we don't have the full code or you run it and see what happens. If it works, it works, if it doesn't work, we have an error to search for.

Comment: Are you getting some from of error when making the call?  Hard to say if it is right or wrong as the api specs of the other application are not available.  However, fundamentally, the cfhttp call is correct.